# Python Selenium: How to get the innerHTML from element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, innerhtml, getattribute

I want to get get the innerHTML from a element but when it run it get error say:

```
findtable.get_attribute('innerHTML')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Code trials:

```
#findtable
findtable = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/center/img")

findtable.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: `driver` is not defined.  which modue is it from ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_elements*` returns a *list*, where as to identify a single element you need `find_element*`.

Additionally, [`get_attribute()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) is a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) method.

---

### Solution

You need to change `driver.find_elements()` as `driver.find_element()`, you'll be good to go.

Your effective code block will be:

```
findtable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/center/img")
findtable.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `driver.find_elements()` use `driver.find_elements()` without `s` at the end

```py
findtable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/center/img")
findtable.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```